# How to search huge data on multiple column with different datatypes?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a `DataElement` table like this:

```
 DataElement table 
 ValueAsBoolean : bit nullable
 ValueAsDatetime : datetime2 nullable
 ValueAsDecimal : decimal(10,3) nullable
 ValueAsInt : int nullable
 ValueAsString : nvarchar(100) nullable
```

The data will look like this:

| ValueAsBoolean | ValueAsDateTime | ValueAsDecimal | ValueAsInt | ValueAsString |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | 2022-09-03 12:30:01.210 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | 23.000 | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | 5 | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | MONTARY INC. |

I want to search data across all columns that match the input search keyword.

- for `ValueAsDatetime` can be searched by TIME ZONE and format show on UI
- for `ValueAsBoolean` can be searched by text "TRUE", "FALSE" or part of "TRUE" or "FALSE"
- for `ValueAsString`, `ValueAsInt`, `ValueAsDecimal` can be search by part of input text

For example given 2022-09-03 12:30:01.210 is Tue, 9 Sep 2022

User input "T".

Output will be rows

- 1 because "T" match with ValueAsBoolean 1 (**T**RUE)
- 2 because "T" match with "**T**ue, 9 Sep 2022"
- 5 because "T" match with "MON**T**ARY INC."

So, I create query base on EF core by:

1. convert all column into String value
2. format the value
3. check value contains the search keyword or not

The query will look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM [DataElement]
WHERE 
    (([ValueAsBoolean] IS NOT NULL AND (('T' = N'')
    OR (CHARINDEX('T', LOWER( CASE WHEN ValueAsBoolean = 1 then 'true' else 'false' END)) > 0))) 
    OR ([ValueAsDateTime] IS NOT NULL AND (('T' = N'') 
    OR (CHARINDEX('T', LOWER( FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, SWITCHOFFSET( [ValueAsDateTime], DATEPART(TZOFFSET, ValueAsDateTime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' ))), 'ddd, d MMM yyyy H:mm:ss' ))) > 0)))) 
    OR ([ValueAsDecimal] IS NOT NULL AND (('T' = N'')
    OR (CHARINDEX('T', LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [ValueAsDecimal]))) > 0)))) 
    OR ([ValueAsInt] IS NOT NULL AND (('T' = N'')
    OR (CHARINDEX('T', LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), [ValueAsInt]))) > 0)))) 
    OR ([ValueAsString] IS NOT NULL AND (('T' = N'')
    OR (CHARINDEX('T', LOWER([ValueAsString])) > 0)))
```

The problem is that when the data is huge (more than 500000 records) it takes a long time to process (more than 30 seconds) and exceeds the query timeout limit.

My question is how to search huge data on multiple columns like this?

The one option I think is to create new column as NVARCHAR(100), convert and save data on multiple COLUMN into this column, set the index to the column and search only that column, but I cannot apply search format for datetime.

Or is there another solution for this?

Comment: "...I want to search data across all column that match input search keyword..." -- If you are considering all data in the database should behave like strings, then stored them as strings. The internal format of other data types won't make it easy to search by their string form. Also, the current design will make your searches awfully slow.

Comment: @TheImpaler the data in database store in proper datatype, but when introduce search function, it causes the problem. I don't want to search all columns in database, but some columns on the table I focus. So for the datatype that not string column I want to apply search, I need to create the new column for that?

Comment: Make the columns primary keys.  SQL support multiple columns as keys.  A hash is created to make search quicker.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @WeanichSanchol One option is to create an extra string column with all searchble columns combined, and search over it. Or, you can create this extra column in a [materialized] view to avoid polluting the table. Or... you could also use bona fide Full Text Search.

Comment: In my experience, it doesn't really serve users to have such a one-size-fits-all search function in, what I think is, an EAV setting. If they type "T" they're really not after dates or booleans. Also, if they type "34" they're really not interested in every number containing 34. I mean, how meaningful is it to get `34` and `123.873411` as results? It gets even more complicated when regional settings come into play. In short: try to narrow it down to text search only.

Comment: After added new column for searching, I still get the response time problem it is less than the first approach, but I think it can increase it, now I'm trying to sync data to elastic search and try to query from that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. With this code, you can search in all the fields of all the database tables. With a little change, you can add the table name as a filter and search only in the desired table:

```
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
SET @SearchStr = 'Put Search String Here'
CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')
WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName =
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )
    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
                AND    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )
        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END  
END
SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
DROP TABLE #Results
```

Comment: the problem is when search like operator for the column with a lots of records it exceed time limit, and I want to fix that problem.

Comment: You can use Full Text Search in SQL Server @Weanich-Sanchol

Comment: I try full text search in SQL server but when I search ADL the records with ADL001, or ADL001/400 are not show up.